# Hide text if one custom field out of two is empty

Tags: custom-field, page-template

I am calling my custom fields into my page template like this:

```
the team donated
<!-- display funds raised -->
<?php $givingback_details_funds = get_post_meta($post->ID,'givingback_details_funds', true); if ($givingback_details_funds == '') { ?>
<!-- display nothing if there is no entry for funds raised -->
<?php } else { ?>
<!-- display this if there is another entry -->
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'givingback_details_funds', true); ?>
<?php } ?>
<!-- display days donated -->
<?php $givingback_details_days = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'givingback_details_days', true); if ($givingback_details_days == '') { ?>
<!-- display nothing if there is no entry for days donated -->
<?php } elseif ( isset($givingback_details_days) && $givingback_details_days == "1" ) { ?>
<!-- display this if entry for day is '1' -->
one working day
<?php } else { ?>
<!-- display this if there is another entry -->
<?php echo $givingback_details_days ?> working days
<?php } ?>
```

This displays great if the post has only one value. Example: “the team donated £300” or “the team donated one working day”.

But I can’t figure out how to get the word “and” to appear between the two values. Example: “the team donated £300 and one working day” instead of “the team donated £300 one working day”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP function `implode()` lets you stick multiple strings from an Array with another string between them. If there's only one value in the Array, then the string that goes between items won't appear.

So you can start by creating an Array. Then, if there's values for your meta, put the values into the Array and `implode()` them with `and` as the string. You can also check if the Array is empty and avoid outputting at all if it is:

```
$giving_back = array();

$givingback_details_funds = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'givingback_details_funds', true );

if ( $givingback_details_funds ) {
    $giving_back[] = $givingback_details_funds;
}

$givingback_details_days = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'givingback_details_days', true );

if ( $givingback_details_days ) {
    $giving_back[] = _n( 'one working day', $givingback_details_days. ' working days', $givingback_details_days );
}

if ( ! empty( $giving_back ) ) {
    echo 'the team donated' . implode( ' and ', $giving_back );
}
```

Also notice that I used the WordPress function [`_n()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_n/) to output different strings based on whether `$givingback_details_days` is greater than 1 or not.

Comment: Thank you for this. The _n() function is very useful, but how would I add an elseif for a value? for example: they might enter "£0", so I'll want to display nothing. And how can I show the currency symbol (£) before $givingback_details_funds? Sorry for so many questions, I've never used array's like this before.